# Elastic Beanstalk Custom Nginx conf

Tags: nginx, php, elastic-beanstalk

I'm setting up a new Amazon Linux 2/PHP/NGINX environment and I'm a little unfamiliar with Nginx since my last environment on Elastic Beanstalk was Amazon Linux/PHP/Apache. (Amazon changed the proxy to Nginx from Apache and the underlying platform was upgraded from Amazon linux to AL2)

Previously, I had an .htaccess file to handle multiple domains where a domain would have a corresponding folder that it would be served from. But, I know that .htaccess file won't work with Nginx.

So far I've tried adding a config file to the .ebextensions folder with something like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: https://someothersite.com/example.com.conf
```

The source being referenced (example.com.conf) contains this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html/example.com;
        index index.html index.php;
        server_name example.com;
   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }
}
```

I thought I needed to create a symbolic link, so I have another config file in the .ebextensions folder that contains this:

```
commands:
  10_link:
    command: sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com
```

After this ln command, I get an error during build. If I don't do that command I don't get an error, but it doesn't work (example.com/test.php wouldn't be served)

My last attempt was to do nothing in the .ebextensions folder and I created .platform/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf with the contents of

```
server {
            listen 80;
            root /var/www/html/example.com;
            index index.html index.php;
            server_name example.com;
       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
    }
```

This seems to be closer as example.com/test.php is going to the file, but the server is prompting the browser to download the php file instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. For test purposes you can simply create files inside the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder
2. For multiple domains you can use

   server_name  *.domain1.com custom.domain2.com;
3. Lastly, we need to process all PHP files via the FastCGI(on Ubuntu you can install it `apt-get install php7.0-fpm`) interface to PHP-FPM.

   ```
   server {
   listen       80;

   server_name  mydomain.com; 

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  combined; 
   location / { 
       root   /var/www/html; 
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;     
   } 
   location ~ \.php$ { 
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock; 
       fastcgi_index index.php; 
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
       include fastcgi_params; 
   } }
   ```

Comment: It's worth noting that Amazon Linux 2 no longer seems to include: `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` in `nginx.conf`, so dropping files in sites-enabled will no longer work. `.conf` Files in `conf.d` will still work though.